# Adding classes based on different conditions by data-ng-class

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have the following code in Angular.js in which I am trying to toggle 2 classes based on toggling conditions made of variable - togglequadkey.

```
<span class="quad-icon" data-ng-class="'quad-icon':!togglequadkey, 'teeth-icon':togglequadkey"></span>
```

I am somehow always getting first class only for span with console errors on the above line. Can someone help?

I am also adding code for its function:

```
$scope.togglequadkey = false;
$scope.togglequad = function() {
    $scope.togglequadkey = $scope.togglequadkey === false ? true : false; 
};
```

Comment: FYI `$scope.togglequadkey = $scope.togglequadkey === false ? true : false; ` is the same as `$scope.togglequadkey = !$scope.togglequadkey;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use object syntax without wrapping object in `{}`

try:

```
data-ng-class="{'quad-icon':!togglequadkey, 'teeth-icon':togglequadkey}"
```

Comment: You did it dude! .. ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using angular v.1.1.4+ you can use ternary operator which allows to use shorthand to specify two different classes, one if an expression is true and one for false.

```
data-ng-class="togglequadkey ? 'teeth-icon': 'quad-icon'"
```